Access Denied Error When Submitting Webform With Event Payment
I have a Webform that is using the CiviCRM Webform module to collect payment for an event.  After entering payment the following error is shown:

I have checked the following things:

This error comes for both a member role and my admin role
I have verified that the user (user role) can make contributions using Core CiviCRM pages
I have turned off the payment for this form and the form can complete as expected without the error.
I have greped my code base (including Drupal and CiviCRM) and I cannot find the error "Authentication/Authorization Failed Username/Password is incorrect"
I wrote a custom listener and I am trying to do extra logging for instances of AccessDeniedHttpException and there does not appear to be an access denied exception when this error is being thrown

I am using Drupal 9.5.11, 6.1.8, Webform CiviCRM 6.2.4, and CiviCRM 5.64.4.
I believe this was working in the past in my dev environment that I do not have right now. I have checked all related code for this form and it is not checking access or making permission changes.
Any help to figure out what is going on here is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Steve

Hi Steve - it would help a bit if you confirmed that payments were working via CiviCRM event pages, to help understand if the problem is specific to webform.

@petednz-fuzion, thank you.  I thought I included it.  I figured out the problem today.  They used to use PayPal and now use Authorize.net.  The Webform was set for PayPal.  Still does not explain how an error message is there that does not appear to be in the code.  Either way it is solved. :)
